# log4j to database

Tags: java, log4j

I used log4j to report error to database:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CUBRID

# CUBRID Database
log4j.appender.CUBRID = org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.CUBRID.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
log4j.appender.CUBRID.user = postgres
log4j.appender.CUBRID.password = postgres
log4j.appender.CUBRID.URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/logs
log4j.appender.CUBRID.sql = INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%x','%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS}','%C','%p','%m')
log4j.appender.CUBRID.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

I have a code:

```
public class LogTest extends BaseDAO<Object> {

    public void show()
    {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class.getName());
        log.info("Wystartowal");
        log.warn("Trwanie aplikacji");
        try {
            if ( 1 / 0 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Czekaj...");
            }
        } catch( Exception ex) {
            log.error("Komunikat bledu", ex);
        }
        log.fatal("Koniec aplikacji");
    }
}
```

All writes to the database but it saves me all the logs and I'd like to I would write only what I give myself using commands log.warn (), log.fatal (), etc.
How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by adjusting the logLevel. Try to change the value like this

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, CUBRID
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change the log level to something else than `DEBUG`.

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, CUBRID
```

This tutorial is very very comprehensive: [Short introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

---

To only log your own info messages but allow other warnings that are >= `WARN` change to the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, CUBRID

log4j.logger.LogTest = INFO, CUBRID
log4j.additivity.LogTest = false

# CUBRID Database
log4j.appender.CUBRID = org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.CUBRID.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
log4j.appender.CUBRID.user = postgres
log4j.appender.CUBRID.password = postgres
log4j.appender.CUBRID.URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/logs
log4j.appender.CUBRID.sql = INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%x','%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS}','%C','%p','%m')
log4j.appender.CUBRID.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Here I am assuming that `LogTest` is not part of any package. If you have put it in a package then change the two lines to include the package (here I use `my.package`:

```
log4j.logger.my.package.LogTest = INFO, CUBRID
log4j.additivity.my.package.LogTest = false
```

---

Now if you want to apply the `INFO` level on all your loggers in your package then do this:

```
log4j.logger.my.package = INFO, CUBRID
log4j.additivity.my.package = false
```

Or even on top level package:

```
log4j.logger.my = INFO, CUBRID
log4j.additivity.my = false
```

Comment: OK, you want info to be logged? Change `WARN` to `INFO`.

Comment: Yes, but when i change to INFO it logged all info, but I want only if I use log.info() in my code

Comment: Beacuse I must write log4j.logger.my.package.XXX for all my package. I want universal solution

Comment: No you don't. You can just use the top level package if you want to. I will show you in my answer.